# Cryptocurrency payment gateway database schema

Tags: database, payment-gateway, payment-processing, cryptocurrency

I am trying to figure out a simplified database schema for a **cryptocurrency payment gateway**. A payment processor allowing merchants to get paid in cryptocoins like *Bitcoin* or *Dash*, supporting payment notification API callbacks too. The payment gateway creates a wallet for the merchant, the customer sends their favourite currency to the wallet and the merchant can then withdraw.

[image: database schema]

This is what I've come to so far, consisting of a *user* table with login info, a *merchant* expansion table for sellers and lastly the supported currencies.
For the financial part, payments are linked 1:1 to a transaction containing relevant info about the actual payment, like blockchain *tx_id* and confirmations. I tried to keep it quite general to avoid tight coupling to a specific coin. Wallet amounts and transaction info are obtained by querying the blockchain. The *transaction* table exists to allow easier control of movements of funds, especially for privacy coins.
Wallets are generated on a separate server and indexed in the db by the address.

Now, there are some noticeable problems and limitations with this db architecture.

First of all, **this database schema**, as for now, **does not support external wallets**.
Considering coins will move into the system from an external wallet (customer paying) and will go to an outer wallet (merchant withdrawing), how can I map those transactions within the database? Does the system need to map them, considering the existence of the blockchain?

Secondly, **how to deal with privacy coins**, where wallet amounts and transaction info isn't public?

Lastly, where should **refunding** be mapped? A transaction linked to the payment or a separate table?

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates? I am facing similar problems now

Comment: Switched to smart contracts